# How is the Future object used in Python's asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I understood the basic idea of an Event Loop. There is a central loop listening to a set of file descriptors, and if it is ready for read or write, the corresponding callback is executed.

We can use co-routines instead of callbacks as they can be paused and resumed. However, this means that there should be some *communication protocol* between the co-routine and the event loop to make things work right?

I wrote a simple Echo Server with co-routines, which would yield the fd along with the interested action like this `yield fd, 'read'`, `yield fd, 'write'` etc and then the Event Loop would register the `select` accordingly. The callback would be to just resume the co-routine. It works fine and I have added the code below.

Now I am just trying to understand how `await` actually works. It doesn't seem to yield fds and the corresponding action like my example code, instead, it gives you a `Future` object.  So what exactly happens under-the-hood? How is it communicating with the Event Loop?

My guess is that `await async.sleep(1)` would be the executed like this:

1. Event loop will be executing the co-routine and reaching `async.sleep(1)`.
2. It will create a `Future` Object.
3. It will then create an fd probably using `timerfd_create` with a callback to complete the `Future`.
4. It will then submit it to the Event Loop to monitor.
5. `await` will yield the `Future` Object to the Event Loop which is executing it.
6. The Event Loop would set the `Future` object's callback function to just resume the coroutine.

I mean I can make use of `Future` like this. But is this what is actually happening? Can someone help me in understand this a little better?

PS: `timerfd_create` was just taken as an example because I couldn't understand how timers can be implemented in an Event Loop. For this question's purpose, network fds would be fin too. If someone can help me on how the timer is implemented that would nice too!

Here is my implementation of a simple Echo Server using co-routines:

```
"""
Tasks are just generators or coroutines
"""
import socket
import selectors

select = selectors.DefaultSelector()
tasks_to_complete = []

def create_server(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    s.bind((hostname, port))
    s.listen(5)
    print("Starting server on hostname at port %s %s" % (hostname, port))
    return s

def handle_clients(s):
    while True:
        print("yielding for read on server %s" % id(s))
        yield (s, 'read')
        c, a = s.accept()
        t = handle_client(c)
        print("appending a client handler")
        tasks_to_complete.append(t)

def handle_client(c):
    while True:
        print("yielding for read client %s" % id(c))
        yield (c, 'read')
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0:
            return "Connection Closed"
        print("yielding for write on client %s" % id(c))
        yield (c, 'write')
        c.send(bytes(data))

def run(tasks_to_complete):
    while True:
        while tasks_to_complete:
            t = tasks_to_complete.pop(0)
            try:
                fd, event = t.send(None)
                if event == 'read':
                    event = selectors.EVENT_READ
                elif event == 'write':
                    event = selectors.EVENT_WRITE
                def context_callback(fd, t):
                    def callback():
                        select.unregister(fd)
                        tasks_to_complete.append(t)
                    return callback
                select.register(fd, event, context_callback(fd, t))
            except StopIteration as e:
                print(e.value)
        events = select.select()
        for key, mask in events:
            callback = key.data
            callback()

tasks_to_complete.append(handle_clients(create_server(9000)))

run(tasks_to_complete)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrote a simple Echo Server with co-routines, which would yield the fd along with the interested action like this `yield fd, 'read'`, `yield fd, 'write'` etc and then the Event Loop would register the `select` accordingly.

This is similar to how Dave Beazley's [curio](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio) works. To learn more about the concept, see this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) where he builds an event loop from the very basics. (He uses the pre-3.5 `yield from` syntax, but it works exactly the same as `await`.)

As you discovered, asyncio works a bit differently, although the principle is still similar.

> Now I am just trying to understand how `await` actually works. It doesn't seem to yield fds, and string corresponding to the action like the above example, instead it gives you a `Future` object.  So what exactly happens under-the-hood? How is it communicating with the Event Loop?

The short version is that blocking coroutines use a global variable (through `asyncio.get_event_loop()`) to fetch the event loop. The event loop has methods that schedule callbacks to be invoked when an interesting event occurs. `asyncio.sleep` [calls](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a3f19c3f52ddff85dd52eaa01b77b2d50cc9af3f/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L531) `loop.call_later` to ensure its resumption when the timeout elapses.

The `Future` that is yielded is just a convenient way for the event loop to be notified of the result once it's ready, so that it can correctly resume the `Task` (coroutine driven by the event loop) that was awaiting the blocking operation, while also handling exceptions and cancellation. See [`Task.__step`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a3f19c3f52ddff85dd52eaa01b77b2d50cc9af3f/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L192) for [the gory details](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a3f19c3f52ddff85dd52eaa01b77b2d50cc9af3f/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L244).

> `timerfd_create` was just taken as an example because I couldn't understand how timers can be implemented in an Event Loop.

Timers are implemented so that the event loop keeps track of both file descriptors and timeouts, and [issues a `select`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a3f19c3f52ddff85dd52eaa01b77b2d50cc9af3f/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1702) that terminates when the [earliest timeout](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a3f19c3f52ddff85dd52eaa01b77b2d50cc9af3f/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1677) elapses. Dave's lecture linked above demonstrates the concept succinctly.

Comment: Thank You so much! I will watch Dave Beazley's lecture and try to the understand the main similarities and differences.

Comment: Great answer. Just for confirmation:  [As David showed](https://github.com/dabeaz/concurrencylive/blob/master/aserver.py#L27), in AsyncIO there should be an intermediate socket involved for futures(He used `socketpair`). Event loop listens to *that* socket using `select` stuffs and when they are ready, event loop `call_soon`s the [`__step`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L259) and again `__step` will yield a Future and so on...

Comment: AsyncIO framework in stdlib also takes advantage of threads in order to use futures, right? That was interesting.

Comment: @S.B *AsyncIO framework in stdlib also takes advantage of threads in order to use futures, right?* - no, asyncio is single-threaded. The only exception is support for executing legacy blocking code from a coroutine, which is implemented using a thread pool. Native asyncio code uses no threads, the magic is in the centralized polling and the use of async calls throughout.